Can two Blazor WASM clients communicate with each other in local network?
Is it possible in a blazor wasm webapp, that two clients communicate with each-other (e.g. via sockets)?
With desktop apps this obviously was possible. Now with WebAssembly, web-apps can run offline. And I wonder, would it be possible to "install" the WASM app as an app offline, then disconnect from the internet, connect to a local network, and share updates with another wasm client? (e.g. by using a broadcast for discovery etc.? Perhaps by using Http and exposing a webapi within the webassembly app?).

for websocket you need a server , you can make one of local pc as server for local or you can use WebRTC , this one is supported what you want

So can this be a different server than the Blazor-Hosting Webserver?

Yes I think you can communicate with a different server, but your second server needs to allow either * -->(Only on local network!!!) or specific address or domain/sub domain in its  CORS configuration. As long as it stays local, Its a bit of a blur since I researched that like 2 years ago, but I wanted to connect to different devices that all were compatible to my app and if I remember correctly(We choose to have different cached version for each), this was achievable if CORS was ok.

Just as an example, when I debug my app from VS, I change localhost to the ip address of the device I want to connect to
#if DEBUG_PROXY
client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mylocalAddress") };
#endif
And my CORS on the device server in debug mode is configured to allow it.

Ok. Now I heared of the same origin policy...Wouldn't this be a problem in combination with changing the address that the http-client tries to connect to? Or does this not apply to a newly instantiated http-client?

I also found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and I wonder if these websockets can be handled similar as normal sockets in native apps. So could a webassembly client simulate the "server" so two clients can talk to each other?...

Browser cannot become server for any external application or clients on other network, that is because there is no port listening API setup in web browser and I don't think there ever will be.
You will need some web server to communicate with, as browsers are designed to contact a webserver or use local apis (manifest with service). Multiple instances of same browser can communicate with each other on the same machine.
As others have mentioned, you have to install web server in your local intranet to communicate between other people on the same network. And you will need SSL setup as many APIs are now only available under secure context.

Thanks for the answer! So I believe the lack of port listening also forbids the use of websockets for this?

@Apahdos yes, browser can never act as a server, but you can use electron js and you can setup a server, electron js allows you to write native app where you can access everything however users need to install the electron js app explicitly for it to work. VS Code and Github for Desktop all are built using electron js.
